# Modify url by adding prefix string

Tags: apache, http, url-rewriting, webserver, url-mapping

I have a http configuration like this, where I have added a prefix pod1 while accessing app1. Without the prefix pod1, app1 uRl is working perfectly.

e.g.

So if user wants to access `http://appserver1:7001/app1` he should use `http://appserver1:7001/pod1/app1` in browser.

But with the prefix pod1, I am able to access app1 url, able  to login, but its breaking the response(response url drops the pod1 prefix) coming from webserver and breaking the application URL(like logout, and other responses)

```
<Location /pod1/app1>
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
    WebLogicHost appserver1
    WeblogicPort 7001
    ProxyPass http://appserver1:7001/app1
    ProxyPassReverse http://appserver1:7001/app1
 </Location>
```

Do I need a rewrite rule here for the URL mapping ?

Comment: you are missing arguments for ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse

Comment: @c4f4t0r , what exactly is missing ?

Comment: for example ProxyPass /pod1/app1 http://appserver1:7001/app1

Comment: @c4f4t0r appserver1:7001/app1 is the actual url to the application.

Comment: I so happy that you solved

Comment: @c4f4t0r Its solved, but as a workaround. Application is working fine but its still dropping the prefix pod1 from the url, when the response come back from appserver1.

Answer (score 0):

Without using Location directive, I used the reverse proxy directly which resolved the issue.

```
SetHandler weblogic-handler
WebLogicHost appserver1
WeblogicPort 7001
ProxyPass /pod1/app1 http://appserver1:7001/app1
ProxyPassReverse /pod1/app1 http://appserver1:7001/app1
```